# Image of closed sets under a continuous function

Tags: continuity, compactness

I have seen the following result
$f :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function.
Then $f(A)$ is bounded for all bounded subsets $A$ of $\Bbb R$. How to prove it?

Also in above result, if we replace the word "bounded" by closed then is it a result? If yes, then how to prove it ?

Comment: You can use Bolzano's theorem that the values of a continuous function on a compact set are bounded. Note that if you take the closure of the bounded set, you get a new, larger set, that is closed and bounded. Since the values of $f$ are bounded in that larger set, then it will be bounded by the same bounds in the smaller original set. For image of a closed set you can take $f(x)=e^{x}$. Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is closed and $f(\mathbb{R})=(0,+\infty)$ is not.

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ is bounded in $\Bbb R$, then $\overline A$ is compact, therefore $ f\left[\overline A\right]$ is compact. Since compact sets are bounded and $f\left[\overline A\right]\supseteq f[A]$, the claim is proved.

Consider the map $\arctan:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, the image if which is $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ for the second.

Comment: Is closure of f(A) = f(closure of A) ? Also tell me that is it true for continuous map only ?

Comment: Some discontinuous maps send bounded sets to bounded sets. It is true that bounded subsets of $\Bbb R$ satisfy $f\left[\overline A\right]=\overline{f[A]}$ for all continuous functions $f$.